# How to split into stages the process of creating a thousands nodes programmatically

Tags: drupal-8

i need to import xml file to Drupal 8 and create nodes based on it content. I try to do it in file .theme (I can't create custom modules), so my plan is:

1. get xml file content and parse it;
2. create array with parsed data;
3. "foreach" data and create node in each step of the cycle (using Node::create)
   and it works, but there is a problem if I need to create several thousand nodes (for example 10 000, there are huge files xml), the process may take an hour (and of course I can't use Maximum execution time = 0, it's limited 30 seconds).

Are there any ways to split the process into stages? I tried to use batchs, but if I understood correctly, they can only be used with forms. Also I thought to use Queue, but I'm not sure if I can use Queue in the .theme file.

Please help me with an idea how to split the process into stages

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Drupal 8 migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/migrate-module/migrate-overview) to configure and process your import. The migrate module is a part of Drupal 8 core so should not require any new modules to be created, and is one of the most common techniques for importing large quantities of nodes or other Drupal data (such as taxonomies).

The migrate module automatically deals with the batch processing issue and will also let you roll-back your migration if there is some issue with the data.

You can find tutorials for working with XML data here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-xml-json-or-soap-source

Alternatively, you can use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. Feeds is designed for ongoing imports such as with an RSS feed that gets constantly updated, but can also be used for one-off imports.